# consult-find - live preview result without close minibuffer?

Tags: consult

Emacs 27.1

package consult.

Here my init.el for package "consult":

```
    (use-package consult
  :bind (
     ;; C-c bindings (mode-specific-map)
         ("C-c M-x" . consult-mode-command)
         ("C-c h" . consult-history)
         ("C-c k" . consult-kmacro)
         ("C-c m" . consult-man)
         ("C-c i" . consult-info)
         ([remap Info-search] . consult-info)
         ;; C-x bindings (ctl-x-map)
         ("C-x M-:" . consult-complex-command)     ;; orig. repeat-complex-command
         ;; Filtering: press "b" -> space = [Buffer], "f" -> Space = [File], "m" -> Space = [Bookmarks] and so on.
     ("C-x b" . consult-buffer)                ;; orig. switch-to-buffer
         ("C-x 4 b" . consult-buffer-other-window) ;; orig. switch-to-buffer-other-window
         ("C-x 5 b" . consult-buffer-other-frame)  ;; orig. switch-to-buffer-other-frame
         ("C-x r b" . consult-bookmark)            ;; orig. bookmark-jump
     ("C-x C-r" . consult-recent-file)         ;; Select from recent files with preview.
         ("C-x p b" . consult-project-buffer)      ;; orig. project-switch-to-buffer
         ;; Custom M-# bindings for fast register access
         ("M-#" . consult-register-load)
         ("M-'" . consult-register-store)          ;; orig. abbrev-prefix-mark (unrelated)
         ("C-M-#" . consult-register)
         ;; Other custom bindings
         ("M-y" . consult-yank-pop)                ;; orig. yank-pop
         ;; M-g bindings (goto-map)
         ("M-g e" . consult-compile-error)
         ("M-g f" . consult-flymake)               ;; Alternative: consult-flycheck
         ("M-g g" . consult-goto-line)             ;; orig. goto-line
         ("M-g o" . consult-outline)               ;; Alternative: consult-org-heading
         ("M-g m" . consult-mark)
         ("M-g k" . consult-global-mark)
         ("M-g i" . consult-imenu)
         ("M-g I" . consult-imenu-multi)
         ;; M-s bindings (search-map)
         ("M-s d" . consult-find)
         ("M-s D" . consult-locate)
         ("M-s g" . consult-grep)
         ("M-s G" . consult-git-grep)
         ("M-s r" . consult-ripgrep)
         ("M-s l" . consult-line)
         ("M-s L" . consult-line-multi)
         ("M-s k" . consult-keep-lines)
         ("M-s u" . consult-focus-lines)
         ;; Isearch integration
         ("M-s e" . consult-isearch-history)
         :map isearch-mode-map
         ("M-e" . consult-isearch-history)         ;; orig. isearch-edit-string
         ("M-s e" . consult-isearch-history)       ;; orig. isearch-edit-string
         ("M-s l" . consult-line)                  ;; needed by consult-line to detect isearch
         ("M-s L" . consult-line-multi)            ;; needed by consult-line to detect isearch
         ;; Minibuffer history
         :map minibuffer-local-map
         ("M-s" . consult-history)                 ;; orig. next-matching-history-element
         ("M-r" . consult-history))                ;; orig. previous-matching-history-element

  ;; Enable automatic preview at point in the *Completions* buffer. This is
  ;; relevant when you use the default completion UI.
  :hook (completion-list-mode . consult-preview-at-point-mode)

  ;; The :init configuration is always executed (Not lazy)
  :init (message "consult - I'm always here at startup")

  ;; Optionally configure the register formatting. This improves the register
  ;; preview for `consult-register', `consult-register-load',
  ;; `consult-register-store' and the Emacs built-ins.
  (setq register-preview-delay 0.5
        register-preview-function #'consult-register-format)

  ;; Optionally tweak the register preview window.
  ;; This adds thin lines, sorting and hides the mode line of the window.
  (advice-add #'register-preview :override #'consult-register-window)

  ;; Use Consult to select xref locations with preview
  (setq xref-show-xrefs-function #'consult-xref
        xref-show-definitions-function #'consult-xref)

  ;; Configure other variables and modes in the :config section,
  ;; after lazily loading the package.
  :config (message "consult - I'm always here after the package is loaded")

  ;; To correct show Recentf-dirs. M-x consult-dir, then press "r" - [Recentf-dirs])
  ;; But not correct work M-x consult-recent-file
  (add-hook 'dired-mode-hook (lambda () (recentf-add-file default-directory)))

  ;; For some commands and buffer sources it is useful to configure the
  ;; :preview-key on a per-command basis using the `consult-customize' macro.
  (consult-customize
   consult-theme :preview-key '(:debounce 0.2 any)
   consult-ripgrep consult-git-grep consult-grep
   consult-bookmark consult-recent-file consult-xref
   consult--source-bookmark consult--source-file-register
   consult--source-recent-file consult--source-project-recent-file
   consult-buffer
   :preview-key '("M-.")
   :preview-key '(:debounce 0.4 any)
   ;; For `consult-line' change the prompt and specify multiple preview
   ;; keybindings. Note that you should bind <S-up> and <S-down> in the
   ;; 'minibuffer-local-completion-map' or 'vertico-map' to the commands which
   ;; select the previous or next candidate.
   consult-line :prompt "Search: "
   :preview-key '("M-."))

  ;; Optionally configure the narrowing key.
  ;; Both < and C-+ work reasonably well.
  ;;(setq consult-narrow-key "<") ;; "C-+"

  ;; Optionally make narrowing help available in the minibuffer.
  ;; You may want to use `embark-prefix-help-command' or which-key instead.
  (define-key consult-narrow-map (vconcat consult-narrow-key "?")   
  )
```

Now I find files:

```
M-x consult-find
test
```

Here result:

[image]

If I press `M-.` its open selected file and CLOSE minibuffer.
But I need to preview selected files WITHOUT close minibuffer.